# Need SQL to disconnect rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

The header is a bit vague but I try to explain
I have 2 tables OrderPartyRole and PriceRequest.

In the past there was one to many relation.One orderpartyrole could have many pricerequests. This is now changed so it can only have 0 or 1 pricerequest in the model.

But problem is historical data in database.
There many rows of Pricerequest that point to the same OrderpartyRole. According the new rules only one is allowed.

I used this SQL to verify this

```
SELECT Max(pricerequest.orderPartyRole) AS partyrole_Max,
       Min(pricerequest.orderPartyRole) AS partyrole_Min
FROM   orderpartyrole, 
       pricerequest 
WHERE  orderpartyrole.bold_id = pricerequest.orderpartyrole 
GROUP  BY orderpartyrole 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

It return 3287 rows, but ideally this should be 0.

So my concrete question is this.
What condition should I use to set pricerequest.orderPartyRole to be -1 on those cases. Like this

```
UPDATE pricerequest 
SET    pricerequest.orderpartyrole = -1 
FROM   pricerequest 
WHERE  <Some condition>
```

The important thing here is that the SQL should not write -1 to all. It should leave one.

A concrete example

```
SELECT bold_id, orderpartyrole, remark 
FROM   pricerequest 
WHERE  orderpartyrole = 76321050
```

The result is

```
BOLD_ID orderPartyRole  Remark
76322590    76321050    
76964885    76321050    ok att använda export priser?
```

In this case I would choose to set OrderpartyRole = -1 as remark is blank using

```
UPDATE pricerequest 
SET    pricerequest.orderpartyrole = -1 
FROM   pricerequest 
WHERE  Bold_id = 76322590
```

And leave the other row as is.

[image: Model]

Comment: What are the rules for identifying which `pricerequest` to keep? Is it always the highest value `bold_id` for a given `OrderPartyRole`?

Comment: First rule is: If only one remark string is nonblank then keep that.
Second of both are nonblank then I would keep the one with highest value of Bold_id

Comment: I've amended Gordon Linoff's answer to take account of the rules you've specified. As written, if more than one `PriceRequest` row for a given `OrderPartyRole` has a non-empty `remark`, the highest `Bold_id` will be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for this . . . assuming you have no other columns to define uniqueness (such as a date or `identity` column):

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT pr.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderpartyrole 
                                ORDER BY CASE WHEN Remark > '' 
                                              THEN 0
                                              ELSE 1 
                                         END, 
                                         Bold_id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM pricerequest pr
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET orderpartyrole = -1
    WHERE seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: I amended the code in this answer to take account of the OP's ordering rules.

Comment: I switched 0 and 1 to meet requirements. But thanks for the help!